# Conflict between Class Name and Package Name in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the context of the following code:

```
package animal; 
public class lion {
}


package zoo; 
public class animal {
    public class lion {
    }
}
```

When I use 'animal.lion' to declare and instantiate an object

```
animal.lion cub = new animal.lion()
```

Android Studio is recognizing the class 'lion' from package 'zoo'. However, I intend to access the class 'lion' from package 'animal'. How can I achieve this **without needing to change the package names or class names**?

Edit: I am well aware of the naming conventions, but I am in a situation where I am not allowed to edit class or package names. They are all written in lowercase letters, and the package is simply a single word.

Comment: Package names should be lower case, class names should start with upper case. Change your class names.

Comment: As you know in Java, the dot operator is used to access members of a class or package. When you use ```a.c```, Java first looks for a class ```c``` in package ```a```, if it can't find one, it looks for a class ```a``` with a menber ```c```. Since there is a class ```a``` with a member class ```c``` in package ```d```, then Java macths ```a.c``` to the inner class ```a``` with member ```c```.

Comment: @esQmo_ any solution without changing names?

Comment: To access the class ```c``` in package ```a```, you can use the fully qualified name of the class, which includes its package

Comment: This doesn't _ever_ occur in any relevant real world scenario. Or, if somehow it did, the fix is to stop using the deplorably-unconventionally-named library if you can't change the code inside it, or change it if you can.

Comment: After your edit, I'm tempted to ask if the code is not decompiled from an obfuscated source?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment, let's consider a real world scenario (using a, c, d... can be tough and misleading):

```java
package com.example.animals; // com/example/animals/Lion.java
public class Lion {
}


package com.example.zoo; // com/example/zoo/Zoo.java
public class Zoo {
    public class Lion {
    }
}
```

If you want to create an instance of the Lion class from com;example.animals and there is a Lion class in com.example.zoo package, you can do something like:

```java
com.example.zoo.Zoo.Lion zooLion = new com.example.zoo.Zoo().new Lion(); // This refers to the inner class Lion of class Zoo in package com.example.zoo

// To refer to the class Lion in package com.example.animals, use the fully qualified name
com.example.animals.Lion animalsLion = new com.example.animals.Lion();
```

Comment: Let me change your code a bit according to mine

package animal;
public class lion {
}


package zoo; 
public class animal {
    public class lion {
    }
}

I am well aware of the naming conventions, but I am in a situation where I am not allowed to edit class or package names. They are all written in lowercase letters, and the package is simply a single word.

Comment: also edited on my question

Comment: I understand that. Did using fully qualified name solve your issue? Or just to be curious is the code coming from an obfuscated decompiled source?

Comment: yes, it is from decompiled source

Comment: using animal.lion doesn't work

Comment: Well, because this is decompiled from an obfuscated code, many things will not make sense; You'll need to make your own package and put the classes in there. The original code didn't have that structure

Comment: I see, I wonder if there is any solution for this issue though, as I guessed it isn't

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by importing the class c from the package d into the package a. To do this, add the following import statement to the top of the class file in the package a

import d.c;

Comment: it doesn't make sense

Comment: It doesn't, this isn't a salvagable answer.